# Using RDTSC (profiling) NASM syntax gives an increasing value everytime

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, rdtsc

I am trying to profile a 8086 code using NASM with AFD debugger. 
I am trying to use RDTSC(0x0f31) instruction , but values I obtain by subtracting new time stamp from the old one are quite huge and are always increasing . 
I don't know what the problem is .
Here is the code :

```
[org 0x100]

CPUID
RDTSC
xor bx,bx
MOV ECX,EAX
RDTSC
SUB EAX,ECX

mov ax,4c00h
int 21h
```

Comment: What is your CPU (is it real hw or emulator like bochs/qemu)? What is the difference? Note, RDTSC "returns the TSC in EDX:EAX." - in two registers, not in one.

Comment: Yes , I know but the value in EDX changes after a long time so , subtracting EAX generates the same results as would EDX:EAX-EDX:EAX(new) would do . It's real HW. CPU is CI3 4200.

Comment: What is the difference? Can you write it here both in decimal and as hex value? Real non-virtualized HW, no hypervisor? OS? Do you single-stepping your test within AFD debugger between rdtsc commands?

Comment: Yes, Actually I was single stepping . The problem was solved when I used GC command to run it